# Making a public page accessible when Forms Authentication is used

Tags: authentication, iis, web-config, authorization, forms-authentication

We have a website that is protected with Forms Authentication in IIS. We would like to make one page in this website accessible to everyone without any authentication.

All the resources I saw mentions using  tag but it's not working for us for some reason.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="public.htm">  
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="UserLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Both public.htm and UserLogin.aspx are in the same folder. When we browse public.htm, we get 401.2.

If disable Forms Authentication, public.htm is accessible.

---

**UPDATE (5/21):**

Disabled Forms Authentication in  but still getting 401.2 error.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="public.htm">  
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="UserLogin.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In the `location` tag, you should also disable forms authentication.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference (updated the question with added line) @LexLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds just like your anonymous authentication has been disabled or your current login user don't have permission to view the public.htm.

If you are hosting it in VS, please ensusre Enabled anonymous authentication has been selected and you current logon user have permission to access the htm file.

[image]

If you are hosting it in IIS, please ensure anonymous authentication has been enabled and the authorization rule would looks just like

```
<authorization>
      <deny users ="?" />
      <allow users = "*" />
    </authorization>
```

The authentication in **applicationhost.config** would looks like

```
  <location path="Sitename">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />                    
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

And the authorization rule for public.htm would be.

```
<location path="public.htm">  
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Please remember to grant IUSER read permission to access public.htm.

Comment: For simplicity, I have only two pages: index.htm and public.htm. If I enable Anonymous authentication, both are accessible. I would expect index.htm to be blocked but public.htm to be open but it's not working that way... If I disable Anonymous authentication, both are not accessible (There is <location> tag for public.htm).

Comment: @Ned I think you need enable anonymous authentication and add <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization> for <location path="index.htm"> . Anonymous authentication is necessary for form authentication https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio